# How to vertically align elements in horizontal list

Tags: html, css

I have horizontal list, the problem is first element in that list is bigger then the rest. And so, I get something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EPCEs/).

How can I align other elements so that they are "centered" vertically? Mind you, I don't want to make the other `li` elements bigger (or higher), and I know I can do it manually by specifying the top and bottom margins, but I would like to avoid it.

jsfiddle code:

```
<div id="contentDiv">
            <div id="topMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li id='top_logo'></li>
                    <li>
                        1
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        2
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        3
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br style="clear:both" />
            </div>
```

style:

```
#topMenu ul li {
/* box size */
width: auto;
display: table;
float: left;
padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
margin: 5px;
/* color */
background-color:blue;
}


#top_logo{
background-color:red!important;
width:200px !important;
height:60px !important;
}
```

Comment: Does the logo have to be wrapped with the other list items?

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex Not really, as long as it will float left in the parent container, and it will be in one line with ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use line-height in cases like this. In this case, setting it to the height of the container (60px) (edit: Not the container specifically, but the height of whatever element you want the list to be vertically centred with) will yield a vertically centred list item.

```
line-height: 60px;
```

Here's an example forked from your example: http://jsfiddle.net/EPCEs/1/

Comment: the problem is, if you were to set the background color you would notice it spans the whole height, while I want it to span only whatever I set it to.

Comment: What do you want it to look like? My solution seems practical for layout, but if you have a specific design in mind, you'll need to explain.

Comment: your current solution is what I was looking for, the thing is I was wondering if it's possible to get this without manually specifying the margins/paddings. But this works :)